# Import multiple javascript files in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

I got some problems in one of my project (university). I need to create a frontend from a very big spaghetti project.

I need to import multiple javascript file inside my VueJs project.
But those javascript files are actually written very badly and they are calling themselves recursivly.

When I just copy/paste them, they don't recognize each other functions and variables.

In the old project, they have just imported all javascript files directly in the index.html file with multiples `<script src="">`.
How should I import them ?

If I just import with a require, there is just a thousands of errors (not defined, not used, ...).
I can import in each javascript file each function variables with : `import { varA, varB, funcA, funcB, ... } from 'fileA.js'`

But this will be very ugly and horrible to do. I have more than 10 files, with thousands lines in each.

EDIT: 
All javascript files even use some variables defined inside index.html for example...

Comment: If files aren't modules and don't export anything, there won't be any good to import them. At this point you can only load them with `<script` and pollute global scope. Otherwise consider refactoring them to export what you need. You don't need `import { varA, varB, funcA, funcB, ... } from 'fileA.js'` then, you can do `import * as fileA from 'fileA.js'` and refer to fileA properties. Use IDE and a linter to make refactoring more efficient.

Comment: Yes, I already use VSC and jslinter for that, but it's nearly impossible to refactor (I only have 2 months for the entire project).

Comment: I mean that if you refer to varA global in one file, it will be labeled as unavailable in current scope by a linter and you can easily rename it to fileA.varA import. BTW, WebStorm is still better at refactoring. Otherwise, stick to globals like it's done now.